# Command to compress folder on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) server

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ubuntu-10.04

What is the command to compress a folder on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tar -czvf archivename.tgz foldername
```

Comment: but i want to ask you if i want to compress file  i will use the same command ?

Comment: Yes, you can also compress single files like this. Please read `man tar`.

Comment: To compress just a single file i would use gzip (`man gzip`), which is implicitly used by the `z` option in the tar command.

Comment: Replace `z` with `j` (use *bzip2*) or `J` (use *xz*) to get a better compression ratio (most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

“Give a man a fish; you have fed him for today. Teach a man to fish; and you have fed him for a lifetime”

I think it's more appropriate to send Mohammad our friend here to the 'man' program.

```
man -k 'string'
```

searches the man database for programs with the needed string.

So for the next time:

```
man -k compress
```

It would also print out for tar.

And `man tar` will teach him all he needs to know about compressing and uncompressing.

Comment: ServerFault (and all of the StackOverflow communities avoid "RTFM" answers.  It is acceptable to provide the answer and also point out that they can find more information (such as the man page.)

Comment: @gWaldo--Where is this stated? I feel like it would be appropriate in this instance.